# Telethon: Where are the common methods like GetDialogsRequest

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

I can see the following import in [Telethon code](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/88f87f6de2adb136078eaff7ed577f234ad27e60/telethon/telegram_client.py), but I can't find the functions like GetDialogsRequest and others mentioned below in the Telethon github repository. Where are these functions? Are they not part of the the telethon project and I should look elsewhere? I can't see any "functions" module in the tl folder.

```
from .tl.functions.messages import (
    GetDialogsRequest, GetHistoryRequest, ReadHistoryRequest, SendMediaRequest,
    SendMessageRequest)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They **are part** of the Telethon project. Internally, the `telethon` part is omitted (so people can potentially rename the package), but the full import would usually be:

```
from telethon.tl.functions.messages import GetDialogsRequest
```

You can always refer to the [online documentation](https://lonamiwebs.github.io/Telethon/index.html). Every request or constructor has a button to copy the `from foo import bar` line directly to your clipboard.

Note that the generated code is *not* in the repository because they are a lot of files, and I decided to exclude them from `git` to avoid a huge repository. Instead, it is [generated](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon#installing-telethon-manually) once you clone the repository by executing `python3 tl_generator.py`. The `tl_generator.py` takes the `telethon_generator/scheme.tl` file and spits out the generated classes and requests under `telethon/tl/`.

Telegram decided to create the so called "[TL Language](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto/TL)" which is like the definition of all the available methods, types and constructors supported by their API. Anyone can take such `.tl` file and conveniently generate code for any other programming language, such as Python for the case of Telethon.